# Where to store sensitive data inside flutter?

Tags: security, flutter, storing-data

I'm building the authentication with openid-oauth2. I managed to gather access_token, identity_token from auth server. I want to store those values and use those values in each api call. I have several options as I searched.

- **I can use [secure storage package](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_secure_storage)** which can hash the access_token and I can read that value to perform api call.
- **I can use Inherited Widget.** Create a inherited widget on top of my application and read from the inherited widget.
- **I can use Singleton**. Simply create a class which will act as singleton class and store my access_token inside that class.
- **I can use [Shared preferances](https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences)**.

Of course the 2., 3. and 4. options are not secure. However, I don't know whether store those values securely is necessary.

What is the best practice in flutter to store those values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest your first choice flutter_secure_storage which I already use to store token. Its perfect choice for the use case.

> A Flutter plugin to store data in secure storage:
>
> - Keychain is used for iOS
> - AES encryption is used for Android. AES
>     secret key is encrypted with RSA and RSA     key is stored in KeyStore